# Backpack 4.0 Settings Laravel 7 strncmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-backpack

When I try to save settings with "allows_multiple":true, I get ErrorException
strncmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. Who get this error too? Maybe someone knows how to solve it? I will be glad for any help. Thanks.

Array seeder with these options:

```
    [
        'key' => 'payment',
        'name' => 'Payment',
        'description' => 'Choose payment systems',
        'value' => null,
        'field' => '{"name":"value","label":"Value","type":"select2_from_array","options":{"Pay Pal":"paypal","visa":"Visa/Mastercard", "LQQ":"LQQ"},"allows_multiple":true,"default":"LQQ"}',
        'active' => 1,
    ],
```

Comment: please share your code so we could help you

Comment: Hello OMR. I solved this issue but I don't remember how(
It was more than month ago